# NHibernate How to convert a SQL Query pulling from multiple tables to QueryOver

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Hello any NHibernate genius,

Some help/guidance would really be appreciated, I'm a bit stuck!

I have the following SQL query, which I'd like to convert to QueryOver and I'm not sure weather it can be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SQL:**

```
Insert Into #categoryAndItems
Select GlobalRateCategoryId,null,[Description],null, null,null, GlobalRateCategoryId, 2 From [GlobalRateCategory]

Insert Into #categoryAndItems
Select Id,Name, gr.[Description],un.[Description],null,gr.Formula,gr.GlobalRateCategoryId, 1  From dbo.[GlobalRateCategoryVariable] gr JOIN 
dbo.UnitOfMeasure un on gr.UnitOfMeasureId = un.UnitOfMeasureId
JOIN [GlobalRateCategory] grc on grc.GlobalRateCategoryId = gr.GlobalRateCategoryId

Insert Into #categoryAndItems
Select gr.GlobalResourceId,null, gr.[Description], um.[Description],    gr.Rate,grr.Formula, c.id, 0 From #categoryAndItems c JOIN 
GlobalRateResource grr on c.id = grr.GlobalRateCategoryId JOIN
GlobalResource gr on grr.GlobalResourceId = gr.GlobalResourceId JOIN 
UnitOfMeasure um on gr.UnitOfMeasureId = um.UnitOfMeasureId

Select * From #categoryAndItems
order by groupid,id
drop table #categoryAndItems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be converted to `QueryOver`, however why not use a Named Query and an XML embedded resource and then project into a DTO?

```
var results = Session
  .GetNamedQuery("GetCategoriesAndItems")
  .SetResultTransformer(
    new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(CategoryAndItemsDto)));
return results.List<CategoryAndItemsDto>();
```

and your DTO:-

```
public class CategoryAndItemsDto{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Description{ get; set; }
 ...
}
```

This is the embedded XML file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <sql-query name="GetCategoriesAndItems">
  Insert Into #categoryAndItems
  Select ...

  Insert Into #categoryAndItems
  Select ...

  Insert Into #categoryAndItems
  Select ...

  Select * From #categoryAndItems
  order by groupid,id

  drop table #categoryAndItems
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Make sure the ALL column names returned by your select * match exactly the columns in the DTO (remember it is case sensitive)

And the final bit of the jigsaw to tell fluent you have an XML file:-

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
.Mappings(m =>
{
   ...
   m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeEntityMap>();
})
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

note: `SomeEntityMap` is a class in the assembly that contains the XML embedded resource.

Comment: Hello Rippo, thank you for the quick response. I am using fluent NHibernate for mapping of the database. From my research i have come to the conclusion that i would have to execute native sql from NHibernate. Is there a better way? or a way to include stored procedure using fluent NHibernate?

Comment: Hello Rippo, Thank you for your quick response and help. Your solution helped us. Thank you.